# UIScrollView vs UICollectionView vs UIPageViewController for slideshow app

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uipageviewcontroller

I am trying to decide which component is best for a slideshow app - the images fit the screen and are downloaded on demand. There should be paging and only one image is visible at a time unless there is sliding between two images. What I tried so far is to do it with collection view but couldn't fix some bugs connected to orientation changes. Still I'd like to know if it is not the preferred way to do this. I looked at some ready components and apps - they seem to use either `UIScrollView` or `UIPageViewController`. What are the benefits of the three? What are possible issues? Are there any know bugs?